# TypeError: 'str' object object not callable in trivial read_csv example

Tags: python, csv, spyder

I am trying to read a sample csv from the same folder as my .py file but am being presented with:

```
  File "directory etc etc//untitled2.py", line 10, in <module>
    data=pd.read_csv('Sample Data.csv')

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I am a little confused what this is being caused by as my code is exactly 2 lines long:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('Sample Data.csv')
```

The contents of 'Sample Data.csv' is:

```
Student Id,Name
1,Oney
2,Twonie
3,Forthman
4,Forthman
5,Sixone
6,Fifthy
```

The directory looks as such:

[image: Image of directory]
I am aware this isn't specifically a coding question as I don't think there is anything wrong with the code but I would like to know what is causing this.

Confusingly the code worked until I tried to add further operations to it and now does not work even with everything removed bar the two lines quoted above.

I am using:

```
Spyder 3.3.6 
Python 3.7.3 64-bit | Qt 5.9.6 | PyQt5 5.9.2 | Windows 10
```

**Edit:** Code added that broke it:

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv('Sample Data.csv')
cleaner=pd.read_csv('Cleaning list.csv')

cleaner=list(cleaner.itertuples(index=False, name=None))

for a,b in cleaner:
    data.loc[data['Student Id']==a,'Name'] = b

print(data)
```

Comment: why is the C in csv capital? Also, what was the code that you added and then removed? It looks like you might have touched what str() is

Comment: Added the code to the question
i'm not sure why the C is capital but read_csv() is not case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not identified the cause of this but have 'fixed' it.
Closing an reopening did not fix the problem but uninstalling and reinstalling Spyder did.

Answer (score 0):

Hm - for me under linux this did the trick:

```py
pd.read_csv(r"Sample Data.csv")
```

Comment: What does the "r" do?

Comment: @WilliamWade "r" sends a string as raw text, doing away with the need for escape characters. Not sure why it should have a problem with this unless the space is a problem?

Comment: @lioElbammalf As I have said in my answer it looks like there was no issue code but some other issue with my Spyder install